# Xcode versus Visual Studio: Difference in runtime for compiled C++ programs

Tags: c++, xcode, performance, visual-studio-2010

I have a small sorting program in C++ developed using XCode on a 2.4  GHz i7 Macbook Pro (I didn't change any of the configurations, so Xcode is probably using LLVM as compiler).

The program only incorporates very standard operations like calculating sums over (parts) of lists (i.e. no explicit use of pointers or so) and is only using standard types and vectors.

When compiling the same code using CL within Visual Studio 2010 on a 2.4 GHz i5 Notebook the runtime is significantly slower (at least by factor 100).

Are there any well-known performance issues with translations from Xcode to VS like the one I just described?

I haven't changed much in Visual Studio 2010 either: Are there some options for CL to be turned on or off that do the job?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think there should be any notable differences in performance.

Comment: Change from a "Debug" to a "Release" build, and see if things don't improve.

Comment: That did the job! Great! Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The i7 and i5 processors have similar architecture. The two you speak of have the same clock rate, but are different tiers. Therefore, the i5 and i7 are not comparable on a benchmark like this. Only if you installed Windows on your Mac would you get a valid timing for both programs. The i7 is more powerful than the i5. @Jerry Coffins also has a point there.

[Check out the difference between i5 and i7](http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2404674,00.asp)

Comment: Many Thanks for the reference. Also Thanks@Jerry Coffins: I will check on the Debug/Release mode and come back with an answer. For the time being, do you know any good (standard?) reference (preferably books) for Xcode and VS where I can find such things?

Comment: I am aware of the difference in the cpu's but it doesn't explain to me why the compiled code is virtually to slow to be used on the i5 windows machine. I would expect a somewhat slightly longer runtime (like 120% or maybe even 200% of the i7 runtime).

Comment: also, the differing operating systems have various speeds too.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Jerry Coffin's comment, you need to use Shift+F5 combination to run your code without the debugger (yes, there is a debugger for release build as well).